# How to sum model relation with id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm new to Laravel 7. I faced the problem when summing the total and group by id. Actually I able to produce the sum value however I wish to keep other objects at the same time.

Model

```
class Invoices extends Eloquent {

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Payments');
    }
}

class Payments extends Eloquent {

    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Invoices');
    } 
}
```

Expected result

```
   "items": [
                {
                    "sale_id": 1,
                    "item_id": 1,
                    "code": "9789814820791",
                    "qty" :1,
                    "total": "20.00",
                },
                {
                    "sale_id": 1,
                    "item_id": 2,
                    "code": "9789814820790",
                    "qty" :1,
                    "total": "20.00",
                },
              "total_amount" : 40,
            ]
```

Code

```
$results = Invoices::with([
            'payments' => function ($qry) {   
               $qry->select(['sale_id', app('db')->raw('sum(total) AS total_amount')])->groupBy('sale_id');
            }
        ])
        ->get();
```

With the code above, I'm able to get `sale_id` and `total_amount` however the other result was missing. I did tried added `$qry->select(['sale_id','item_id', 'code', 'qty' 'total']);` but it does not work.

Comment: Is your model Invoice(should be singular) or Invoices(plural,not recommended)? In your query(with your class name Invoices) then you should use Invoices::with...

Comment: @Bazsmagister sorry. That's a typo